# Fit QML file to screen

Tags: qt, resize, symbian, resolution, qml

I have created an application with a screen resolution of 640 x 360 for the nokia n8. It includes a lot of flickables, labels, etc. I want it to run on the nokia e6 with a resolution of 640 x 480.

Up to now I have simply copied the the QML file and modified it for the new resolution but it's getting a little tiresome to do it for each update. I want to know if there is any simple way I can get it to automatically fit the output to any screen resolution? Or if there is something else I can do to simplify my task. I would prefer not to use anchors because it makes it too complicated to design the QML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using [`QApplication::desktop()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qapplication.html#desktop)`->`[`availableGeometry()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qdesktopwidget.html#availableGeometry) to set the geometry of your application window?

From the docs:

> **`QDesktopWidget::availableGeometry()`**
>
> Returns the available geometry of the screen with index screen. What is available will be subrect of screenGeometry() based on what the platform decides is available (for example excludes the dock and menu bar on Mac OS X, or the task bar on Windows).

Addressing your comment below:

> does it re size the entire screen

The `const` in `QDesktopWidget::availableGeometry() const` tells you that you can be pretty sure that the function doesn't alter anything. You'll need to do the resizing yourself.

**Edit:** The [QML docs](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qtbinding.html#modifying-properties) should give you the information you need to automatically change your application geometry. You could either change the geometry of the QML object from C++ or define your available screen geometry as a `Q_PROPERTY` and access it from QML. I'd recommend the former, as hooking up to the `signal` [`QDesktopWidget::workAreaResized`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qdesktopwidget.html#workAreaResized) might help you on mobile devices where your available geometery may change.

Comment: I'm I just don't understand does this simply tell me the screen resolution or does it re size the entire screen for?

Comment: I might sound stupid but what do you mean by change geometry of qml object? Do you mean I can change every things size or do I have to change every things size individually?

Answer (score 1):

Actually you should avoid hardcoding the interface pixel by pixel and start using anchors. Ther will be some phones that have yet another screen resolution and then you have to create new QML for each of them. With anchors you can let the content fill all available space

Comment: Thanks I have actually noticed that but I'm a bit lazy and I just wanted to know if there is an easier way?

Comment: How can I get the screen width and height in qml?